# Побитовый оператор ~ (не)

Tags: javascript, java, c++, php

Добрый день. Я имею число 9 (1001) - в двоичной системе. И когда провожу побитовую операцию ~ (НЕ),  то получается число (0110) - в двоичной системе, в десятичной равно 6, как я понимаю. Но источник http://learn.javascript.ru/ считает, что:

```
9 (по осн. 10) 
= 00000000000000000000000000001001 (по осн. 2)
           --------------------------------
~9 (по осн. 10) 
= 11111111111111111111111111110110 (по осн. 2) 
= -10 (по осн. 10)
```

Прошу, подскажите, где моя ошибка.

Comment: @dors, первый бит отвечает за знак целого.

[wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B5_(%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)#.D0.A6.D0.B5.D0.BB.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D1.81.D0.BE_.D0.B7.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.BC)

Comment: @dors, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

[@dors](/users/31843/dors), Ваша ошибка в том, что для положительных чисел Вы не учитываете лидирующие нули. В реальной жизни они присутствуют, их количество зависит от размера (типа) переменной.

Answer (score 0):

Оператор тильда (побитовое НЕ) - выполняет для целых чисел преобразование `-( n + 1 )`.
Так что верно они написали.

Answer (score 0):

Самый левый бит — это бит знака. Если к 11111111111111111111111111110110 прибавить 1010, то получится 0, поэтому это число кодирует -1010 в двоичной системе исчисления.

Подробнее: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Дополнительный_код_(представление_числа)